# Select dates between two years

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

- Person (ID, Name, age)
- Rents (ID, DATE, DURATION)

Note: `ID` in table '`Rents`' is the person's `ID`.

I need to find the people who have any rent in 2007.

My query:

```
select * 
from person 
natural join rent 
where date(DATE, 'yyyy') > date(2006, 'yyyy') 
  and date(DATE, 'yyyy') < date(2008, 'yyyy');
```

But I get the following error message:

> ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 10 Column: 98

Comment: What datatype is column `DATE`?

Comment: Which database and version are you using? I'm confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get away with just using the `YEAR` function here:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM person p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM rent r WHERE p.ID = r.ID AND
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM r.date) = 2007)
```

This would return all people having at least one rent activity in the 2007 calendar year.  If you want something else, then maybe you should show us some data.

Comment: I think function `YEAR()` does not exist in Oracle. Use `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ...)`

Comment: @Tim, please help me out, I cannot find a function `YEAR` in Oracle. What database / version is this?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Google, the black hole of useful information: https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefyearfunc.html

Comment: @Tim, how am I supposed to google for something called `YEAR`? And does JavaDB generate 'ORA-00936' errors?

Comment: The link refers to JavaDB which is mention anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is the inner Date variable in `date(DATE, 'yyyy')` the inner date method needs some parameters. I think you want to have the current date in this function? Then use:

```
date(CURRENT_DATE, 'yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

You have three options:

```
CREATE TABLE person (id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR2(50), age NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE rents (id REFERENCES person(id), rent_date DATE, duration NUMBER);

INSERT INTO person (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Donald');
INSERT INTO person (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Dagobert');
INSERT INTO rents (id, rent_date) VALUES (1, DATE '2018-08-03');
INSERT INTO rents (id, rent_date) VALUES (2,  DATE '2017-05-02');

SELECT *
  FROM person
  JOIN rents USING (id)
 WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM rents.rent_date) = 2017; 

SELECT *
  FROM person
  JOIN rents USING (id)
 WHERE TO_CHAR(rents.rent_date,'YYYY') = '2017'; 

SELECT *
  FROM person
  JOIN rents USING (id)
 WHERE rents.rent_date BETWEEN DATE '2017-01-01' AND DATE '2017-12-31';
```

If you kindly add the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements to your next post, you will increase the chance that somebody is finding the correct answer...

Comment: Of course, I just stuck to the OP's join to sort out the error message.
`DISTINCT` won't help much if there are two rents in a year. I'd use your `SELECT ... WHERE EXISTS`.

Comment: If the OP just wants a list of unique people with rental activity, then you probably want `SELECT DISTINCT`.  Persons with more than one 2007 rental activity would be duplicated by a join.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another solutions.

With join:

```
select p.* 
from persons p
join rents r on p.id = r.id
where extract(year from r.date) = 2007;
```

Without join:

```
select p.*
from persons p, rents r
where p.id = r.id and extract(year from r.date) = 2007;
```